# Finding a bound of rational sequence for a sequence converging to zero

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of positive real numbers converging to $0$, can we find a sequence of the form $\left\{\frac{1}{2^n}\right\}$ such that there exists $m,n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ with
$$x_n^m\leq\frac{1}{2^n}\qquad\text{for all }\ n\geq n_0$$

Intuitively, it seems right (and sometimes wrong)! My approach of reasoning: -

Since $x_n\longrightarrow0$, $x_n<1$ for $n\geq n_0$. Therefore, one can make $x_n$ small enough by taking its $m$th power so that
$$x_n^m\leq\frac{1}{2^n}\qquad\text{for all } n\geq n_1$$
where $n_1\geq n_0$.

I would be grateful if someone could clear my doubts on this. Thanks!

Comment: Questions:
1. Where $k$ plays the role?
2. You need to quantify $m$. There exists $m$? For all $m$?
Moreover, the order of quantifiers about $m$ and $n_0$ is important.

Comment: Yes @DannyPak-KeungChan. I made some edits and hope it make sense now.

Comment: I think that $x_n=1/n$ is a counter-example as $n^m/2^{n}$ converge to $0$ if $n\to +\infty$ (for a fixed $m$).

Comment: Thanks @Kelenner

Comment: @Kelenner, Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Kelenner has pointed out, if we consider the sequence $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}$, then for a fixed $m$, $\frac{n^m}{2^n}\longrightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, i.e.,

$$\frac{1}{n^m}>\frac{1}{2^n},\ \ \ \ \ n\geq n_0 $$

for sufficiently large $n_0$ and hence the wrong conjecture.